# Yii: Format of dataProvider in CGridView

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid, yii, grid

What is the array format to display the data in **CGridView**.

I'm sending the array to **dataProvider** but nothing is comming in browser.

I'm using below code in my models

```
 public function ExtensionList()
        {
                        // I'm Using 2 database So I'm calling db2->createCommand
                        $row = Yii::app()->db2->createCommand(array(
                        'select' => array('extension', 'date_created'),
                        'from' => 'extensions',
                        'where' => "extension_type = 'EXTENSION'",
                        ))->queryAll();

                        return $row ;

               }
```

my Index.php

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
      'id'=>'extension-grid',
      'dataProvider'=>$model->ExtensionList(),
      'columns'=>array(
              'extension',
              'date_created',
      ),
)); ?>
```

What is the wrong in the below format of array.

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [extension] => 2000 [date_created] =>
>   2013-07-24 21:15:09.993303 ) [1] => Array ( [extension] => 2001
>   [date_created] => 2013-07-24 21:23:07.94538 ) [2] => Array (
>   [extension] => 2002  [date_created] => 2013-07-26 11:58:59.537204 ) )

---

If I used below code, grid is displaying in my another model

```
  $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
                        $criteria->select='service_id,count(*) as counts';
                        $criteria->condition = "sdate between '$this->startdate' and '$this->enddate'";
                        $criteria->group ='service_id';

                   return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                        'pagination' => array( 'pageSize' => 30 ),
                ));
```

I'm using this type to execute query, its  working fine and records are displaying in grid.

But to display the extension list I'm using createCommand, its not working.

```
 $row = Yii::app()->dbcc->createCommand(array(
                        'select' => array('extension', 'extension_type', 'date_created'),
                        'from' => 'accounts',
                        'where' => "extension_type = 'EXTENSION'",
                        ))->queryAll();
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                       'criteria'=> $row ,
                         ));
```

Note: I'm using Yii 1.1.13

Answer (score 0):

The [`CGridView::dataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#dataProvider-detail) property must be set to an instance of `IDataProvider`, you cannot directly set it to an array and expect it to work.

The immediate fix would be to create a [`CArrayDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) and use that:

```
'dataProvider'=> new CArrayDataProvider($model->ExtensionList()),
```

That said, getting the result set with raw SQL like that and feeding it to a dumb `CArrayDataProvider` is not "the Yii way" to do things and hints that you are going the wrong way. It's not clear from the question what you are doing exactly, but consider using a [`CActiveDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) or [`CSqlDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider) instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, Now I'm usnig like this 'dataProvider' => new CArrayDataProvider($model->ExtensionList()), But I'm getting error as Undefined index: id in /var/www/Yii/yii-1.1.13.e9e4a0/framework/web/CArrayDataProvider.php(108)

Comment: you need to specify the id for CArrayDataProvider to uniquely identify each record.

Answer (score 0):

[have a look at CArrayDataProvider documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider)you select the id and use it as unique identifier in CArrayDataProvider

`'dataProvider'=> new CArrayDataProvider($model->ExtensionList(), array('id' =>'extension' ))`,