# disable future dates in CJuiDatePicker or EJuiDateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, yii, datepicker

I'm using Yii, How to disable future dates in CJuiDatePicker or EJuiDateTimePicker. I should not allow users to select future dates in calander.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`maxDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) option of JUI DatePicker, by passing it as part of the `options` array:

```
'options' => array(
    'maxDate' => 'today', // to allow selection of dates upto today only
)
```

---

All the options provided by the underlying jui plugins are provided by their respective CJui* classes in Yii through the `options` property of the [`CJuiWidget` class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiWidget#options-detail).

Comment: Thanks, Can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762013/yii-formate-of-dataprovider-in-cgridview